# How to swap substring in a string?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, date

Let's assume I have the following string:

```
x <-  "22-03-23"
```

Given this and given any other similar string with the same format I want to be able to swap the position of "22" with "23" in an automated way.

Hence, result should be:

```
"23-03-22"
```

The code needs to abstract from those numbers and work in any other scenario with the same format.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is it a date? Are we trying to convert DD-MM-YY to YY-MM-DD?

Comment: I tried in date format using "format" but it didn't work. So, yes, it is fine for a date but if it works for a character even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```r
x <- c("22-03-23", "01-04-20")
gsub("(.*)(-.*-)(.*)", "\\3\\2\\1", x)
#[1] "23-03-22" "20-04-01"
```

Answer (score 3):

Split on `"-"`, then reverse and *paste* it back together, or use *as.Date*:

```
x <-  c("22-03-23", "01-04-20")

sapply(strsplit(x, split = "-", fixed = TRUE), function(i) paste(rev(i), collapse = "-"))
# [1] "23-03-22" "20-04-01"

as.Date(x, format = "%d-%m-%y")
# [1] "2023-03-22" "2020-04-01"
```

If needed we can format how the date is printed:

```
format(as.Date(x, format = "%d-%m-%y"), "%y-%m-%d")
# [1] "23-03-22" "20-04-01"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
x <- "22-03-23"
result <- x %>%
  str_split("-") %>%
  unlist() %>%
  rev() %>%
  paste(collapse = "-")
print(result)  # prints "23-03-22"

# Using base R
x <- "22-03-23"
parts <- strsplit(x, "-")[[1]]
result <- paste(rev(parts), collapse = "-")
print(result)  # prints "23-03-22"
```